# Digitally Signature Protected when individual cells are protected Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have VBA code that locks individual cells when double clicked which is ok.

**Problem.** However the protecting of individual cells is affecting my digital 
signatures i have on my excel sheet. I am not able to double click on thee digital signature if the individual cells are protected.

Question: Is there a way around this?

[image]

Below is the code which i use to protect the cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
                Sheets("Sheet3").Protect Password:="Test", userinterfaceonly:=True
                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username")
                    .Value2 = .Value2 & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
                     .Locked = True
                    End Select
                 End If
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit cells that are already locked you will have to unlock them, modify, and then lock them again. Alternativley you could change your VBA code to lock the worksheet opposed to cells. In this case the within the method "Protect" there is an argument "[UserInterFaceOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel/)". This argument allows you to prevent changes from the UI but not macros.

```
 Sheets("Sheet1").Protect "password", UserInterFaceOnly:= True
```

Comment: I have added my code to the question. I had used UserInterFaceOnly prior to this and i was getting the same problem.

Comment: Are there multiple users? I see you have & Environ("Username"). If you were to only allow certain users the ability to edit you could write something such as. If Environ$("UserName") = "Admin" and then unlock the sheet entirely to allow edits.